# Websphere slow URLConnection

Tags: java, websphere, urlconnection

We have a Websphere version 6.1 deployed on a Linux environment. To open an https connection we call `openConnection()` and `connect()` on a `java.net.URL` object.

Opening this connection takes aproximately 3 minutes. Once the connection is established we can write and read data very fast.

Using openssl a connectiontest (`ssh` console) works very fast. A simple jar application deployed on the same machine, outside of the container, works normal too, but once deployed in websphere the problem occurs.

We only have this problem in a Websphere 6.1, works fine in 6.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

An application on the same JVM set the https.proxyHost and http.proxyPort system properties which made our connection go slow. (proxy could not find url in these 3 minutes and used a direct connection afterwards..).